# $sgn(X) = sgn(E(X \vert \mathcal{G}))$ almost surely

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables

This is the exercise 5.1.12 of Probability: Theory and Examples by Rick Durrett. We want to show that $sgn(X) = sgn(E[X \vert \mathcal{G}])$ almost surely.

My approach: If $X>0 (=0, <0)$ a.s., then $E[X \vert \mathcal{G}]>0 (=0, <0)$ a.s.

Now if $E[X \vert \mathcal{G}]>0$ a.s., it means that $E[X \vert Y]>0$ for any $Y \in L^{0}(\mathcal{G})$. We want to show that $X>0$ a.s. By contradiction assume that there exist $A \in \mathcal{G}$ that $P(\omega \in A)>0$ and $X \leq 0$ on A (that is $X(\omega) 1_{\{\omega \in A\}} \leq 0$). Then, set $Y = 1_{\{\omega \in A\}}$ and $E[X \vert Y] = E[X \vert 1_{\{\omega \in A\}}] = E [X 1_{\{\omega \in A\}} \vert 1_{\{\omega \in A\}}] \leq 0$ which is a contradiction.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, your solution has an issue that you cannot assume such $A \in \mathcal{G}$ exists. For example, consider the case when $\mathcal{G}$ is trivial and $X \sim \text{Uniform}(-1, 1)$. The original problem assumes that $\Bbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}]$ has the same distribution as $X$, and this is a very crucial assumption. You need to use this.

Comment: @SangchulLee You are right. I removed my approach.

Comment: @SangchulLee Any idea?

Comment: "I removed my approach." Wrong move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $Y = \Bbb{E}(X | \mathcal{G})$. Then for any Borel measurable $A \subset \Bbb{R}$ we have

$$\Bbb{E}(X \mathbf{1}_{\{X \in A\}}) = \Bbb{E}(Y \mathbf{1}_{\{Y \in A\}}) = \Bbb{E}(X \mathbf{1}_{\{Y \in A\}}).$$

(Why?) Then for $A = [0, \infty)$, writing $X_{+} = X\mathbf{1}_{\{X > 0\}}$ and $X_{-} = -X\mathbf{1}_{\{X < 0\}}$, we have

\begin{align*}
\Bbb{E}(X_{+})
&= \Bbb{E}(X\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \geq 0 \}}) \\
&= \Bbb{E}(X_{+}\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \geq 0 \}}) - \Bbb{E}(X_{-}\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \geq 0 \}}) \\
&\leq \Bbb{E}(X_{+}) - \Bbb{E}(X_{-}\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \geq 0 \}})
\end{align*}

and hence $\Bbb{E}(X_{-}\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \geq 0 \}}) = 0$. Can you conclude from this that $\Bbb{P}(X < 0, Y \geq 0) = 0$? How about $\Bbb{P}(X > 0, Y \leq 0) = 0$?

Comment: In the first equation, the first equality is true because $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. Right? But, for the second equality, I don't understand why it is true. If $1_{\{ Y\in A\}} \in L^0 (\mathcal{G})$, then it is true.

Comment: @m0_as, For the second equality, notice that $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Thus the event $\{Y \in A\}$ is in $\mathcal{G}$.